# can not do jquery hover on div that have z index

Tags: html, css

I have 2 divs one is a big div(like a notepad) and there is a little div(like a bookmark) that is under the big div on the side of it
but now i want to use the hover event on the little div but because it has  z index it doesn't fire.
like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/xf7Ca/8/

i want to do like this:

```
$(document).read(function(){
    $("#bookmark").hover(function(){
       //do something
    });
});
```

how can i have access to the bookmark div?

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to load `jQuery` in your jsFiddle and here is your mistake :

```
$(document).ready(function(){...});
```

not

```
$(document).read(function(){...});
```

You could have found it by yourself using the `console`

**[jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Brewal/xf7Ca/10/)**

Comment: no error if i'm not mistaken.but when i remove the z index from the bookmark the hover event fires.

Comment: You could try adding [`pointer-events: none;`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events) on the bookmark